# Select all groups I'm member of and display members of these groups

Tags: mysql, select

I'm blocked on a query that seems difficult to understand.

I have these tables for example :

```
groups (id, name)
groups_members (id, userid, groupid)
```

I would like to display something like that :

```
Group 1
Member 1
Member 3
Member 4
Member 5

Group 4
Member 1
Member 2
Member 9
```

Select all groups and his members and ONLY if I'm a member of.

I was looking on Union but it seems to be uncorrect.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Should the teamid in groups_members represent the id column in groups?

Comment: you sample is not clear

Comment: Are you wanting to create the query in PHP or directly in SQL? Are there other tables in the database that are relevant to the query (for example, is team_id a foreign key to another table?).

Comment: Ive replaced teamid by groupid. Logic. Thanks Paul.
Directly in sql. There is only 1 foreign key : groups.id to groups_members.groupid

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wish to write a function like

```
function selectIfMember($ID)
```

That, given an ID, returns all groups that have that ID as one of their members.

Your table "groups" contains pairs (none of which are distinct) which are {Group ID, Group Name}, and "groups_members" SHOULD BE a mapping table {Group ID (Foreign Key), User ID (Foreign Key)} (I have no idea why you have an additional ID there as well).

**I have to note here** that the following could be done easier with a full join, but since they aren't implemented directly in mySQL, I'll do it with two queries:

$query1:

```
SELECT GM.groupid, GM.userid FROM groups_members GM
WHERE GM.userid = '.$ID
```

$query2:

```
SELECT * FROM groups
```

Note that if there are n groups, Query2 is now an [n][2] array, where for the i-th group, [i-1][0] is the group id and [i-1][1] is its name.
If there are m users, Query 1 is an [m][2] array where the for the i-th user, [i-1][0] is the group ID for that user, [i-1][1] is that user's ID.

```
foreach($query2 as $value){
    $nameMap[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
```

Now, $nameMap is mapping all the group IDs to names.
Create a temporary array

```
$tempArr =  array();
```

Now, in this associative array, store at the index which is the name of the group, an array of its members:

```
foreach($query1 as $val){
  if(!isset($tempArr[$nameMap[$val[0]]]))
      $tempArr[$nameMap[$val[0]]] = array();
  array_push($tempArr[$nameMap[$val[0]]],$val[1]);
}
```

In the end, for each group, if its name was "groupName", you should have an array of all its users at $tempArr["groupName"].
Now, you might wanna run something like

```
foreach($tempArr as $key => $val){
  echo '<h1>'.$key.'<h1><br>'
      foreach($val as $user){
      echo $user.'<br>'
      }
}
```

To display it all